# KQL query for azure disk free space in GB and free disk percentage using Insights

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I am new to KQL . Can someone please guide me if this query is right?

```
InsightsMetrics
  | where Name == 'FreeSpaceMB'
  | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Tags, Computer
  | extend Drive = tostring(parse_json(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
  | extend Size = toreal(parse_json(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"])
  | project TimeGenerated, Computer, Drive, bin(SizeGB = Size / 1024, 0.1), bin(FreeGB = Val / 1024, 1)
  | join kind=inner (InsightsMetrics
      | where Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
      | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Tags, Computer
      | extend Drive = tostring(parse_json(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
      | project TimeGenerated, Computer, Drive, bin(FreePercent = Val, 1.1))
  on Computer, Drive
  | project TimeGenerated, Computer, Drive, SizeGB, FreeGB, FreePercent
  | order by Computer asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query seems more or less O.K.

A few comments:

- Avoid calling *parse_json* multiple times.
- Summarize only by *mountId* and not the entire *Tags* field (unless you want to get multiple rows in case of change to *diskSizeMB*)
- There is actually no reason to self-join, since you can compute *FreeSpacePercentage*.

```
InsightsMetrics
  | where Name == "FreeSpaceMB"
  | extend Tags = parse_json(Tags)
  | extend mountId = tostring(Tags["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
          ,diskSizeMB = toreal(Tags["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"])
  | project-rename FreeSpaceMB = Val
  | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, diskSizeMB, FreeSpaceMB) by Computer, mountId
           ,FreeSpacePercentage = round(FreeSpaceMB / diskSizeMB * 100, 1)
  | extend diskSizeGB = round(diskSizeMB / 1024, 1)
          ,FreeSpaceGB = round(FreeSpaceMB / 1024, 1)
  | project TimeGenerated, Computer, mountId, diskSizeGB, FreeSpaceGB, FreeSpacePercentage
  | order by Computer asc, mountId asc
```

Comment: Thanks, David. But am not able to get the FreeSpaceGB in the Azure disk alert setup as measure . attaching screenshot below .

Comment: format_bytes() returns a string. I thought you need it for display purpose. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks David . It worked . One last clarification does this query all the partitions together and alert individually ?

Comment: This question is out of scope for this post. If you have doubts regarding how azure alerts work, then please post a new question with the right tagging and context.